# Artifacts when draw polygon with small hole in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, canvas, webkit

I draw polygons with small hole and self-intersection and in some cases get an [artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERvFh.png).

What I tried to fix the problem (and it worked):
 - Increasing the size of the hole ([link](https://jsfiddle.net/wq675px9/3/)).
 - Reducing the size of the canvas ([link](https://jsfiddle.net/wq675px9/2/)).
 - Removing self-intersection ([link](https://jsfiddle.net/wq675px9/4/)).
 - In Mozilla it works fine.

All these fixes are not suitable for my case.

[Full code](https://jsfiddle.net/wq675px9/1/)

```js
const selfCanvas = document.getElementById('selfIntersect');
selfCanvas.width = 300;
selfCanvas.height = 300;

const dx = 50;
const dy = 100;

const selfCtx = selfCanvas.getContext("2d");

selfCtx.fillStyle = 'red';
selfCtx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';

selfCtx.beginPath();

selfCtx.moveTo(5 + dx, 2 + dy);
selfCtx.lineTo(7 + dx, 0 + dy);
selfCtx.lineTo(3 + dx, 0 + dy);
selfCtx.lineTo(0 + dx, 1 + dy);
selfCtx.lineTo(6 + dx, 0 + dy);
selfCtx.lineTo(5 + dx, 2 + dy);
selfCtx.closePath();

selfCtx.moveTo(0, 0);
selfCtx.lineTo(200, 0);
selfCtx.lineTo(200, 200);
selfCtx.lineTo(0, 200);
selfCtx.lineTo(0, 0);
selfCtx.closePath();



selfCtx.fill();
selfCtx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="selfIntersect"></canvas>
```

Is there any workaround?